# How to define a function in first order logic that return different values each time?

Tags: first-order-logic

How to represent f() in first order logic so that following scenario holds?

M=f()
N=f()

where M $!=$ N

Comment: You don't. Axioms of equality deman that $M=N$ if $M=f()$ and $N=f()$.

Comment: how to represent a function f so that $M != N$

Comment: You cannot: a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) in mathematics is a relation between a set of inputs and a set of permissible outputs with the property that each input is related to **exactly** one output.

Comment: But the symbol M=f( ) is meaningless: what is the input value ? When you say "a function that return different values each time?" what do you mean with "each time"? different input values? are there instant of time ?

Comment: Yeah, by definition a function takes exactly one value on each argument. And there is no such notion as "each time" in logic. What you can do however is for instance  to consider a function with one more argument, $t$, express that $t$ ranges over a linearly ordered set, and think of $f(x,t)$ as being the value "at time $t$" of a "function that depends on time".

Comment: Thanks a lot understand....